# How to send <p> tag id value on form_open_multipart?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Is there a way do send the < p > tag id value on form_open_multipart?

like on my html I have

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart("sample"); ?>
    <p id="sample_message"></p>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        document.getElementById("sample_message").innerHTML = "This is my message!";
    }); 
</script>
```

on my controller "sample" || "sample.php" page I want to

```
    echo $this->input->post("sample_message");
```

Comment: you can get by using `p` `text`

Comment: is it safe to use input text then hide?

Comment: so you mean `<input type="text" id="sample_message" style="display: none;"/>`?

Comment: no i mean `<input type="hidden" id="sample_message" name="sample_message"/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `hidden` field in your form

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart("sample"); ?>
<input type="hidden" id="sample_message" name="sample_message"/>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Now assign `value` to hidden filed using `jquery`

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
       $('#sample_message').val('This is my message!');
    }); 
</script>
```

You can get value of  `sample_message` in your `controller` by using

```
echo $this->input->post("sample_message");
```

Comment: for the mean time I will use that code. Wondering to know if there are ways where I can send the value of < p > tag on my controller

Comment: We can send `<p>` tag text to controller

Comment: Yes we can, but inside the `form_open_multipart` it can't

Comment: Okk have you check it. because i am not sure about it.

Comment: Still can't find solution. I think I will just use your answer since it worked on my code. Thanks.

Comment: let me do some R&D in it and let you know